# how to not show the button if the link is a 404 in java?

Tags: java, jsf

I am coming to a issue where I have a button link that goes to a pdf. I need help to check if there is no pdf (404) then do not show the button at all. If it is 200 then show the button. How can I achieve this in java? Thanks !

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#{jobDataHolder.jobpayGrade}" class="btn btn-info-One" target="_blank">Pay</a>
```

Java

```
public String jobpayGrade;

public String getJobpayGrade() {
    return jobpayGrade;
}

public void setJobpayGrade(String jobpayGrade) {
    this.jobpayGrade = "http://WEB_ADDRESS/paygrade/" + jobpayGrade + ".pdf";     
}
```

Comment: is the pdf which needed to be downloaded in the same server?

Comment: no it is not in the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the error code of a page

```
    URL url = new URL(jobpayGrade);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    if(code==200){
        //set visible
    }else if(code==404){
        //set not visible
    }
```

---

If I was implementing it it would look like this somewhat

```
if(isValidURLConnection(jobpayGrade)){
    button.setVisible(true);
}else {
    button.setVisible(false);
}

private boolean isValidURLConnection(String jobPayGrade){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(jobPayGrade);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        return connection.getResponseCode()==200;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt for you're answer. Should I implement it inside my `setJobpayGrade(String jobpayGrade)` method?

Comment: Personally I would put the check in a separate function that returns the error code and handle exception accordingly and based off of the return of the function set the visibility

Comment: So, basically inside my `code==200` I return my web address that I have above, right? And inside my else clause can I return a custom error page something like `/error404.xhtml` ?

Comment: and also do I need to call my method in my front-end?

Comment: Good luck and happy coding If this answer satisfies the question please mark the answer as accepted so others do not think the question is still open

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about your program if you are still having trouble maybe post another question on S.O. to see if others can help